# Accessing __doc__ of function inside a lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, docstring

I would like to extract the docstring of a function once it has been wrapped in `lambda`.

Consider the following example:

```py
def foo(a=1):
    """Foo docstring"""
    return a

dct = {
    "a": foo,
    "b": lambda: foo(2),
}

for k, v in dct.items()
    print(k, v(), v.__doc__)
```

I get:

```
a 1 Foo docstring
b 2 None
```

How can I reference the function called on "calling" the `lambda` one?

## Update

Thanks for all answers:

```py
from functools import partial

def foo(a=1):
    """Foo docstring"""
    return a

dct = {
    "a": foo,
    "b": partial(foo, 2),
}

for k, v in dct.items():
    if hasattr(v, "func"):
        print(k, v(), v.func.__doc__)
    else:
        print(k, v(), v.__doc__)
```

```
a 1 Foo docstring
b 2 Foo docstring
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. I am not sure it is possible, since 'b' is a brand new function altogether that has no docstring. I am not sure if you can introspect into the functions that a function calls.

Comment: You can't, you'd be better off using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) which preserves the wrapped function as the `func` attribute - `functools.partial(foo, 2).func.__doc__`.

Comment: You cannot.  A function can call multiple functions, so how should python know which of the "child" docstrings is the right one?  Best I can think of is to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) on the lambda, which will copy the wrapped function's docstring to the wrapping function.

Comment: There is always the option to "manually" add a docstring to your lambdas, like this `dct["b"].__doc__ = "Lambda docstring"` but I do not know if this fits your actual use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "good" way to do this. However, it is technically possible using the `inspect` module. Here is a very brittle and fragile implementation that fits your use case of getting the docstring of the first function called by a lambda:

```
import inspect
import re

def get_docstring_from_first_called_function(func):
    # the inspect module can get the source code
    func_source = inspect.getsource(func)

    # very silly regex that gets the name of the first function
    name_of_first_called_function = re.findall(r'\w+|\W+', func_source.split("(")[0])[-1]

    # if the function is defined at the top level, it will be in `globals()`
    first_called_function = globals()[name_of_first_called_function]
    return first_called_function.__doc__


def foo(a=1):
    """Foo docstring"""
    return a

b = lambda: foo(2)

print(get_docstring_from_first_called_function(b))
> Foo docstring
```

As I said, this implementation is fragile and brittle. For instance, it breaks instantly if the first function called is not in `globals`. But if you find yourself in very dire straits, you can probably hack together a solution for your use case.

If at all possible, however, you should use functools instead

```
import functools

def foo(a=1):
    """Foo docstring"""
    return a

b = functools.partial(foo, 2)

print(b.func.__doc__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, trying to add features such as docs to smt which by definition should be "anonymous"... could be done only in a tricky way.
I could achieve that using nested decorators.

Notice first that `print('__doc__' in dir(lambda: ''))` is `True`.

```
def add_doc_to_lambda(func, a, docs=''):
    # also provide custom docs parameter
    if docs == '':
        return (lambda l: (lambda _=setattr(l, '__doc__', func.__doc__): l)())(lambda: func(a))
    return (lambda l: (lambda _=setattr(l, '__doc__', docs): l)())(lambda: func(a))

def foo(a=1):
    """Foo docstring"""
    return a

dct = {
    "a": foo,
    "b": add_doc_to_lambda(foo, 2), # add_doc_to_lambda(foo, 2, 'lambda docs') # case of custom docs
}

for k, v in dct.items():
    print('>>> ', k, v(), v.__doc__)
```

**Output**

```
>>>  a 1 Foo docstring
>>>  b 2 Foo docstring   # lambda docs # case custom docs
```

**Remark**:

1. `add_doc_to_lambda` is callable

```
print(dct['b'])
<function dec.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f6eda92ee50>
```

2. Also a more straightforward way such as

```
l = lambda: foo(2)
l.__doc__ = foo.__doc__
print(l.__doc__)
```

works but assignment of lambda function to a variable is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that a different mechanism for your [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) may be appropriate here. Anything that returns a properly wrapped [`FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) is going to have direct access to the correct `__doc__`. One common method would be to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) with [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
from functools import partial, wraps

dct = {
    "a": foo,
    "b": wraps(foo)(partial(foo, 2)),
}
```